# Target css: Background image Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, target

Hello im trying to target a specific css background image here http://22twenty.com/This/

What i want is the white background to fade out once the text has slide up to give it a cool effect.

I need to have it fade out when  slide out is done

```
$.when(slideOutMenu()).done(function() {
    $.when(toggleMenuItems('up')).done(function() {
        initEventsSubMenu();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with CSS3 or just a little of JS...

Check this example I made using jQuery animate: http://jsfiddle.net/9dSD2/1/

Also check http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: and how would i get the text sliding up?